# Error when buiilding Binutils for RISCV Cross Compiler

Tags: cross-compiling, riscv, binutils

I keep getting two error messages alternatingly when building Binutils for a riscv compiler.
The first error message:

../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:219: @include `bfdt.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:219: @include` bfdio.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:244: @include `init.texi': No such file or directory.    ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:246: @include` section.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:248: @include `syms.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:250: @include` archive.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:252: @include `format.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:254: @include` reloc.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:256: @include `core.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:258: @include` targets.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:260: @include `archures.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:262: @include` opncls.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:264: @include `libbfd.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:266: @include` cache.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:268: @include `linker.texi': No such file or directory.    ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:270: @include` hash.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:288: @include `aoutx.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:290: @include` coffcode.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:292: @include `elf.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:296: @include` mmo.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:220: Prev reference to nonexistent node `Miscellaneous' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).    ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:201: Menu reference to nonexistent node` Miscellaneous' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:200: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Error reporting' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:199: Menu reference to nonexistent node` typedef bfd' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?). bfd.info: Value too large for defined data type

Second:

../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:219: @include `bfdt.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:219: @include` bfdio.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:244: @include `init.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:246: @include` section.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:248: @include `syms.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:250: @include` archive.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:252: @include `format.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:254: @include` reloc.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:256: @include `core.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:258: @include` targets.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:260: @include `archures.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:262: @include` opncls.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:264: @include `libbfd.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:266: @include` cache.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:268: @include `linker.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:270: @include` hash.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:288: @include `aoutx.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:290: @include` coffcode.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:292: @include `elf.texi': No such file or directory.   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:296: @include` mmo.texi': No such file or directory.
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:220: Prev reference to nonexistent node `Miscellaneous' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).   ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:201: Menu reference to nonexistent node` Miscellaneous' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).
../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:200: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Error reporting' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?).    ../../../bfd/doc/bfd.texi:199: Menu reference to nonexistent node` typedef bfd' (perhaps incorrect sectioning?). bfd.info: Value too large for defined data type

I'd like to know how come I would get

> Value too large for defined data type

when I am on a 64-bit system.

checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... riscv32-unknown-elf

Comment: What is your makeinfo and texinfo versions? Could you give more information about your system also?

Comment: It was rather stupid. I tried to build the toolchain on a network drive instead of a physical one. Switching to a local directory fixed the issue!